# Dynamically created component styles not working. ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"

Tags: angular

I am dynamically creating a component in my main component.ts file like so:

```
const colorPickerDropdownFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
  ColorPickerComponent
);

this.colorPickerDropdown = this.colorPickerContainer.createComponent(
  colorPickerDropdownFactory
);

this.colorPickerDropdown.instance.left = e.clientX;
this.colorPickerDropdown.instance.top = e.clientY;
```

It works, my the component is getting dynamically created but some reason when I send it styles (last two lines of the code block above), the styles don't work.

I've added the following to the component.ts (ColorPickerComponent) that is dynamically loaded:

```
  left: number;
  top: number;
```

and the .html:

```
   <div class="colorPicker" [ngStyle]="{'left': left}"></div>
```

When checking the console I see `ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"` in the `colorPicker` div. I'm wondering if that means if its trying to set the style but doesn't have the value.

It's weird because when putting a value into the `[ngStyle]` like: `[ngStyle]="{'left': '100px'}"` It kicks in.

and when console.logging `left` and `top` I get the values I want.

What do I need to do to get the variable style to kick in?

Comment: I don't think `e.clientX` will have the units on there. You may need `e.clientX + 'px'`

Comment: Is it because `100px` is a string and you probably are declaring `left` as a `number` and probably also assigning it a number? You generally get this error when `[ngStyle]` is not assigned a valid object.

Comment: o WOW that works! @user184994 i should of caught that. thanks! if you want to put it as an answer ill accept it

Comment: @SiddAjmera correct, i was assigning it a number instead of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `clientX`, the value is simply a number, and it missing the units such as `px`.

Instead, you should do

```
this.colorPickerDropdown.instance.left = e.clientX + 'px';
this.colorPickerDropdown.instance.top = e.clientY + 'px';
```

And change the type to `string`